# What does "work in feet and inches" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

The sentence is

> I still work in feet and inches and have a confirmed allergy to all things computerised.

Link: https://www.lancashiretelegraph.co.uk/news/6022787.really-fit-long-life/

Does "work in feet and inches" mean "to work manually"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of "feet and inches" refers to the [imperial units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) of measurement (for lengths) that were used in the UK before the metric system was formally introduced in the 1970s. Despite the offical system of measurements now being metric, it's still common for people to mix measurements in daily life (people's heights and weights are often quoted in imperial units, for example). Some older workers just find it easier to work in the units that they originally learned than swapping to the new system.

Comment: Not older tradesmen, I think. They have to use metric as all their supplies (wood, piping etc.) are metric. And as for being allergic to things computerized, their mobile phones are grafted at the waist. If the newspaper didn’t give it away, I’d say it was the definition of an American.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add that *work* means do calculations, measure, or use.

Comment: That's a great addition, @YosefBaskin. This helps.